# Is there any way to get a list of files in a directory into a variable when using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

When creating a browser app, there doesn't seem to be any way to get a list of files in a particular location using javascript. In Nodejs this is easily done using `fs`.

Basically I have a directory called images/, and I want to manipulate a list of all the files as a javascript variable without having to manually create the list of files. I thought that since webpack bundles all of the files that there might be some way to generate the list as a JSON file (or an alternative) which could be read in with javascript -- though I haven't found any way to do that yet.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Webpack runs on nodejs so this is easily done using `fs`.

Comment: @Bergi Can you elaborate? I wasn't able to get fs to work because this app runs in the browser. That's why I thought generating a file at build time would be a reasonable solution, if it exsited.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about [plugin code running in webpack during build](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/), not about the code that is being built and will run in the browser.

Comment: I see. I will look into that, thanks. If you feel inclined to give an example as a full answer, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a plugin:

`src/plugins/FileLister.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class FileLister {
  constructor(options) {
    if (!options || !options.path || !options.outputFile) {
      const msg = "Please specify the path and outputFile options.";
      throw new Error(msg);
    }
    this.options = options
  }
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap({name: 'FileLister'}, () => {
      const files = fs.readdirSync(this.options.path)
      fs.writeFileSync(this.options.outputFile, JSON.stringify(files));
    })
  }
}

module.exports = FileLister;
```

Then in my `webpackage.config.js`:

import:

```
const FileLister = require('./src/plugins/FileLister.js')
```

plugins section:

```
new FileeLister({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/important_files/'),
  outputFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/important_files.json')
}),
```

This creates a file called `important_files.json`  in the `dist` directory containing a list of the files in `src/important_files/`.