# How do I include a JSON file to my javascript that's generated at compile time with a webpack plugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Following up from my previous question, which I was able to solve:
[Is there any way to get a list of files in a directory into a variable when using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167467/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-into-a-variable-when-usin)

I am trying to figure out how I can do something like
`import important_files from 'important_files.json'` in my javascript, so that I can utilize the JSON data without having to read it in with `File`.

Currently, my generated file goes to the `dist` directory, and I technically can include it from there, but that seems wrong to me. Is there a way to make the file able to be included by including it in the build assets at compile time?

Is there a totally different approach that's superior?

Thank you.

Comment: Putting the file in the `dist` directory is totally fine. I have used something similar to have a configuration file loaded at the start. To generate it for each build you could modify the "scripts" from your `package.json`. Example: `"build": "./scripts/generate-file-list.sh && vue-cli-service build"` (but with the webpack equivalent for building, forgot what it is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to generate the file in the `src` directory, where it gets included -- then use the `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy it over to the `dist` directory